# Does obeying the Torah lift God's imprecation against the ground?

Tags: law, blessings

According to the LES, the first part of Deuteronomy 28:12 says, "May the Lord open to you his good treasury, the heavens, to give rain for your land in season, to bless all the work of your hands..."

Recognizing that a blessing is the opposite of a curse, would the latter part of the former part of Deuteronomy 28:12 (... bless all the work of your hands ...) suggest that obeying God's commandments will lift the ground's curse God imprecated against in Genesis 3?

Comment: Even if followed absolutely, the transgression of the first humanity (in Adam) still needs to be accounted of, in righteousness. (And who is able to follow 'absolutely' ?)

Answer (score 3):

Deuteronomy 28:1-2 NKJV

> 28 “Now it shall come to pass, if you diligently obey the voice of the
> Lord your God, to observe carefully all His commandments which I
> command you today, that the Lord your God will set you high above all
> nations of the earth. 2 And **all these blessings shall come upon you
> and overtake you, because you obey the voice of the Lord your God:**

It's true that obedience to God's commandments is essential for experiencing blessings and favor from God. Including agricultural prosperity. However, **the full elimination of the curse on the ground will happen when all things are redeemed and restored in Christ.** This restoration is described in Romans 8:19-23, where creation itself is described as groaning in anticipation of its liberation from bondage to decay and corruption.

Romans 8:19-23 NKJV

> 19 For the earnest expectation of the creation eagerly waits for the
> revealing of the sons of God. 20 For the creation was subjected to
> futility, not willingly, but because of Him who subjected it in hope;
> 21 **because the creation itself also will be delivered from the bondage
> of corruption into the glorious liberty of the children of God.** 22
> For we know that the whole creation groans and labors with birth pangs
> together until now. 23 Not only that, but we also who have the
> firstfruits of the Spirit, even we ourselves groan within ourselves,
> eagerly waiting for the adoption, the redemption of our body.